# Which documents do I need to apply for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, zimbabwean-citizens

I have been invited by a friend in Germany to visit her, and she is going to pay all my expenses since I do not have any bank account. I have her affidavit, travel medical insurance, application form, my passport, and my lodging to prove where I will be staying initially.

Is this everything I need, or am I missing anything?

Comment: I've edited your question a bit to make it more readable. Notice that I've put several words in brackets to show what I've added. If those are not correct or alter the meaning, you can undo/roll back my changes.

Comment: Do you have ties to your home country and if so, do you have proof of that? Without proof of ties to your home country you will find it harder to get visa, often it is even impossible.

Comment: Thank you very much ,as much clarity is there now .My last question is that can you help me with whats those ties means and how they work ?

Comment: Your chances of getting a visa under these circumstances are almost nil with the economic situation in Zimbabwe and you not having any financial backing. It is a Hail Mary shot. You may want to reconsider this expedition.

Comment: The roundtrip/onward ticket is missing from your list, but I agree with @SheikPaul that this is a futile attempt in your circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

You bank statements have several purposes.

- They show how the expected costs of travel will be paid. Having someone else pay helps in this regard.
- They show that you have a job or other ties to your home and that you are **not likely** to become an illegal immigrant in Germany. Having someone else pay for the trip does not help in this regard.

It might help if your friend is willing and able to sign a [Verpflichtungserklärung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verpflichtungserkl%C3%A4rung_(Ausl%C3%A4nderrecht)), which means that she will reimburse the state for all costs if you do not leave on schedule. Depending on her income, she might be required to post a bond to do that.

*Regarding the comments:* Imagine a suspicious consular official. You have to convince him that you will go **back to Zimbabwe**. What are your reasons to do that, and can you explain them so the official will understand?

- A steady, well-paid job is best.
- Owning a house or a farm would help, too.
- Having family who do not come on the trip *may* help. The officials might wonder if you want to work in Europe to support them or if you will return to them.
- Just having unexplained money (or gifts from distant relatives) is a **very bad** thing. The officials would wonder if you expect to pay it back by working in Europe.